# Wheel rolls hitting curb, how is the force of the curb on the wheel related to the initial velocity of the wheel?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, velocity

To find the force for a wheel to scale a curb one must find where the force forwards produces a torque that is larger than that of the weight of the wheel but how can one relate this to the intitial velocity of the wheeel?[image]

Comment: consider the angular momentum relativ to the edge it touches.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a dropped ball will bounce higher if it hits the ground at a higher speed, if a wheel hits a curb at a higher speed it will experience a greater loss of horizontal momentum and a greater gain in vertical momentum. There are many variables:  Is the wheel free of mounted? What are the sizes of the wheel and curb? What is the initial speed? The magnitude and direction of the force from the curb will depend on friction and deformation of the tire, and will change with time and as the wheel rises.